# Call Dialog from ManagedBean now showing PrimeFaces 5

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

What I need to do call I dialog from a ManagedBean, exactly like this show case:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/basic.xhtml

It looks very trivial but I'm new to JSF and maybe there is something the showcase assumes I should know to make it work.

what I did was quite similar to showCase:

file myDialog.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Dialog Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
.ui-widget {
    font-size: 90%;
}
</style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Dialog Working</h1>
</h:body>
</html>
```

In the page "client" page:

```
<p:commandButton value="Open Dialog" ajax="true"
                actionListener="#{testMB.open}"
                 />

public void open() {
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("myDialog");
}
```

When I try to call the dialog nothing happens!

In the Firebug Console I got the "Widget for var 'widget_frmBody_j_idt88' not available!"

I noticed the .xhtml file from showCase does not have a  so I tried this approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <p:dialog widgetVar="testDialog">
        <h1>This is a Dialog</h1>

    </p:dialog>

</html>

RequestContext rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
rc.execute("PF('testDialog').show()");
```

And I got:

TypeError: PF(...) is undefined jquery.js:1
"Widget for var 'testDialog' not available!"

What can I do to make it works please???

Answer (score 0):

This is my example for you.

XHTML

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="1">
        <p:commandButton value="Basic" 
                         process="@this" 
                         update="@form" 
                         actionListener="#{dialogView.openDialog}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:dialog header="Basic Dialog" 
              widgetVar="dlg1" 
              minHeight="40">
        <h:outputText value="Dialog open!" />
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

ManagedBean

```
public void openDialog() {
    RequestContext rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    rc.execute("PF('dlg1').show()");
}
```

Comment: Should the dialog xhtml page be separated, or it can be inner of a large xhtml page?

Comment: @SajjadHTLO you can use p:dialog both seperated page and nested inner of a large xhtml page. However, I suggest you to seperate p:dialog to another page and includes to your large xhtml page.